# Service worker freeze during installation in chrome v72 on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have page that is pwa application, everything works fine until I got update chrome to 72.0.3626.76 on android. And now when I deploy new version of sw it freeze during instalation and sw is not working - same issue on my Android phone and on emulator. I tryied this scenario with app from this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/ and same - after updating sw installation freeze.

Here is screenshot from devtools [image: screenshot]

Here is link [for demo app from tutorial](https://pwa-test-ff64d.firebaseapp.com). There is no error, nothing.

It's working fine for older chrome but on 72 it freeze. Did you had this issue? How can I solve it?

### update1:

[reported bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=929023) This bug only occurred during remote debugging

Comment: This might be a bug. You can report it or see if it's reported/fixed on crbug.com.

Comment: thanks, I've reported bug, waiting for answer

Comment: Looks like Chrome 73 (at least the build that comes preinstalled on Q Preview) suffers from the same issue. How the hell am I supposed to develop and test service workers like this? :(